# Create a powerpoint presentation with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, powerpoint

I'm in a situation in which I have to build a PowerPoint presentation programatically and serve the resulting ppt file through a web application, preferably using Rails, JavaScript or Ruby. Is this possible? If so, how and with which tools?

I'm open to any and all suggestions on how to best tackle this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be a powerpoint file or would creating a HTML presentation that runs in a fullscreen browser be enough?

Comment: It needs to be a powerpoint file.

Comment: OK; so you are talking about serverside JavaScript?

Comment: Or client side. I'm not adverse to using Node, or anything similar.

Comment: What part of the creation process needs to happen clientside? Isn't it just the download?

Comment: Take a look at [**this**](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00246_Create_a_PowerPoint_presentation_from_a_plain_text_file.htm)

Comment: Anyway, you know how Microsoft is about it's products, you surely wont find any documentation about how to do this besides deprecated VB stuff. I'd just give up con PP and use something like [**Prezi**](http://prezi.com/)

Comment: I simply can't fathom the requirements process that led to this.

Comment: @nicooga Thank you for the suggestion! I'll explore that possibility

Comment: @Bergi Images/graphs/reports are created, need to be built into a .ppt that needs to be available to download.

Comment: @MarkThomas BUSINESS....

Comment: If this is a report, why not PDF? There are more libraries available to create PDF reports.

Comment: @MarkThomas I know, and its a proposal (as well as xls), but business requires a PowerPoint export option, and its non-negotiable.

Comment: You may also look at You could also take a look at https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/powerpoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://tomasvarsavsky.com/2009/04/04/simple-word-document-templating-using-ruby-and-xml/

If you can create the template and populate the values, consider this approach.

> Office Open XML file formats
>
> The new Office file formats (.docx, .xlsx, .pptx files) are basically a zipped collection of XML files. We focused on Word files
> (.docx) but this approach would work with any of the other types of
> files as well. The specification for the format weighs in at several
> thousand pages. Producing a file from scratch without a purpose built
> library that handles all the intricacies of the format would be quite
> a task. Instead, we drafted the templates in Word and placed markers
> to tell our templating engine where to insert values. We created
> document properties which reference data values and added these as
> fields into the document in the place where the values should be
> inserted. For example, we could have fields like:

```
label_tag #{data[:user].name}
label_tag #{data[:user].address}
label_tag #{data[:booking].number}
label_tag #{data[:booking].items.collect{|i| i.name}.join(‘,’)}
```

Otherwise, there was an attempt (WIP uploaded three years ago, I do not expect it to be completed, but should be benfecial in creating an approach to create slides) on creating PowerPoint slides.  Here is a sample of the code

https://github.com/jpoz/rubypoint/blob/master/lib/rubypoint/presentation.rb

```
def new_slide
  RubyPoint::Slide.new(self)
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll be looking into this tonight!

Comment: This is perfect guidance, I'm accepting it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution using this? I have similar problem

Comment: @Joelio I did end up building a rudimentary PPT, but they requirements changed before I could delve much into it.

Answer (score 6):

This ruby gem seems more mature than the one mentioned in the current accepted answer.

https://github.com/pythonicrubyist/powerpoint
http://rubygems.org/gems/powerpoint

```
require 'powerpoint'

@deck = Powerpoint::Presentation.new

# Creating an introduction slide:
title = 'Bicycle Of the Mind'
subtitle = 'created by Steve Jobs'
@deck.add_intro title, subtitle

# Creating a text-only slide:
# Title must be a string.
# Content must be an array of strings that will be displayed as bullet items.
title = 'Why Mac?'
content = ['Its cool!', 'Its light.']
@deck.add_textual_slide title, content

# Creating an image Slide:
# It will contain a title as string.
# and an embeded image
title = 'Everyone loves Macs:'
image_path = 'samples/images/sample_gif.gif'
@deck.add_pictorial_slide title, image_path

# Specifying coordinates and image size for an embeded image.
# x and y values define the position of the image on the slide.
# cx and cy define the width and height of the image.
# x, y, cx, cy are in points. Each pixel is 12700 points.
# coordinates parameter is optional.
coords = {x: 124200, y: 3356451, cx: 2895600, cy: 1013460}
@deck.add_pictorial_slide title, image_path, coords

# Saving the pptx file to the current directory.
@deck.save('test.pptx')
```